# Initialization of map with a list as value

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, stdmap, initializer-list

I am trying to initialize a map that contains a list

```
map<string, list<int>> firstNamesMap = {{"name1", new list<int>}};
```

I get the following error:

```
error: could not convert ‘{{"name1", (operator new(8), (<statement>, ((std::list<int>*)<anonymous>)))}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::list<int> >’
 map<string, list<int>> firstNamesMap = {{"name1", new list<int>}};
                                                                 ^
```

I was originally trying to initialize a much larger map with `list<Data *>` instead of `list<int>`, in which "Data" is a simple class declared earlier. It produces the same error either way though.

Not sure if it matters, but I'm compiling with g++ in Cygwin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new list<int>` results in a *pointer to a `list<int>`* (i.e., `list<int> *`). However, looking at the *mapped type* of your `map`:

```
map<string, list<int>> 
            ^^^^^^^^^
```

What you actually need is a `list<int>`, not a `list<int>*`.

---

Try with `list<int>()` instead of `new list<int>` when initializing the map:

```
map<string, list<int>> firstNamesMap = {{"name1", list<int>()}};
```

Comment: Or, even shorty: `map<string, list<int>> firstNamesMap = {{"name1", {}}};`.